# c++ Identifier Undefined

Tags: c++, playstation3

I'm an PS3 Developer I'm Making a Menu 
But i can't figure this out 
It tell me Console_write is undefined 
But its litterly Underneath it , when i click on consle_write 
and Click on go to definition = i and up on my console_write Funtion
https://i.gyazo.com/12ed53334c4ca12b288bc705a3196b89.png

Its not only with Console_write

--> take a look if you want https://i.gyazo.com/490989ab1af58c15d063cd831d1708f2.png

i need a Quick Solution , If any C++ coder is willing to help to get this Project to work you'r free to P.M me

i need 10 Reputation to post images on the thread ...

Comment: Please don't post important and relevant information in external links. Please include all relevant information in your post.

Comment: For instance, you can post a code snippet instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that at the time the compiler is parsing that line, it does not know that `Console_write` exists. You either need to pre-declare the function or move its definition above the offending line.